# C# - implementing interface methods with different complex input parameters, per implementation

Tags: c#, generics, interface

What I want to achieve is simple: for an interface like so:

```
public interface ITestInterface
{
    void SomeMethod(InputDataBaseClass inputData);
}
```

I would like to have multiple implementations like so:

```
public class TestInterfaceImp1 : ITestInterface
{
    public void SomeMethod(InputDataDerivedClass1 inputData)
    {

    }
}

public class TestInterfaceImp2 : ITestInterface
{
    public void SomeMethod(InputDataDerivedClass2 inputData)
    {

    }
}
```

and so on. **InputDataDerivedClass1** and **InputDataDerivedClass2** are derived from **InputDataBaseClass**:

```
public class InputDataBaseClass
{

}

public class InputDataDerivedClass1 : InputDataBaseClass
{

}

public class InputDataDerivedClass2 : InputDataBaseClass
{

}
```

So, in the end I would be able to declare something like:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public ITestInterface TestInterface { get; set; }
}
```

Inject either **TestInterfaceImp1** or **TestInterfaceImp2**, and call **SomeMethod** with the appropriate input data type.

OK, I realize we can't do something like this directly because method signatures on interface implementations must match. I also realize that the common workaround is to declare a generic interface like so:

```
public interface ITestInterface<T> where T:InputDataBaseClass
{
    void SomeMethod(T inputData);
}

public class InputDataBaseClass : ITestInterface<InputDataConcreteClass1>
{
    public void SomeMethod(InputDataConcreteClass1 inputData)
    {

    }
}
```

However, this won't compile:

```
ITestInterface<InputDataBaseClass> t = new InputDataBaseClass();
```

even though, **InputDataConcreteClass1** inherits the **InputDataBaseClass**... so I would have to either convert **every** class that uses the **ITestInterface** to a generic:

```
public class SomeClass<T>
{
    public ITestInterface<T> TestInterface { get; set; }
}
```

OR declare the interface type explicitly:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public ITestInterface<InputDataConcreteClass1> TestInterface { get; set; }
}
```

Which is counterproductive to the whole idea... Or am I missing something?

**I guess my question is:** is there any better approach? Or is that a limitation of interfaces in C# and there is no way to have a method that takes different input data for different implementation?

**Edit1:**

OK, I know I can do that using casting inside the implementation:

```
public class Impl1: ITestInterfaceT
{
    public void SomeMethod(InputDataBaseClass inputData)
    {
        InputDataDerivedClass1 cast = inputData as InputDataDerivedClass1;

        System.Console.WriteLine(cast.A);
        System.Console.WriteLine(cast.B);
    }
}

public class Impl2 : ITestInterfaceT
{
    public void SomeMethod(InputDataBaseClass inputData)
    {
        InputDataDerivedClass2 cast = inputData as InputDataDerivedClass2;

        System.Console.WriteLine(cast.A);
        System.Console.WriteLine(cast.C);
    }
}

public interface ITestInterfaceT
{
    void SomeMethod(InputDataBaseClass inputData);
}

public class InputDataBaseClass
{
    public string A { get; set;}
}

public class InputDataDerivedClass1 : InputDataBaseClass
{
    public string B { get; set;}
}

public class InputDataDerivedClass2 : InputDataBaseClass
{
    public string C { get; set;}
}
```

But this is exactly what I'm trying to avoid; without compile-time type checking, this will be a rather fragile code - is there any better way?

**Edit2:**

The problem I'm facing is that the implementation of my interface has to implement a method that processes the same logic but use slightly different input data in each implementation. **For example**, I have method **SaveData** - one implementation saves it to the database and requires data plus a set of foreign keys, while the other saves it to the disk and requires data plus the file name. Until now, I always did it by inserting all required data in the constructor of the implementation and then calling the SaveData method (which was either parameterless or with a single parameter), like so:

```
public interface IDataSaver
{
    void SaveData(string someData);
}

public class ToDiskDataSaver : IDataSaver
{
    private string FilePath { get; set;}

    public ToDiskDataSaver(string filePath)
    {
        this.FilePath = filePath;
    }

    public void SaveData(string someData)
    {
        //save file to disk here
    }
}

public class ToDatabaseDataSaver : IDataSaver
{
    private long DataForeignKey { get; set; }

    public ToDatabaseDataSaver(long dataForeignKey)
    {
        this.DataForeignKey = dataForeignKey;
    }

    public void SaveData(string someData)
    {
        //save file to database here
    }
}
```

and so on.

**This works perfectly**... but I'm looking for a way to make it work when a method needs complex input parameters - different for each implementation (without inserting them in the constructor). Perhaps this can't be done...

Comment: What about a generic argument and a non generic base interface? However what's the point of an interface where you may give the wrong argument at compile time?

Comment: Just because `InputDataConcreteClass1` inherits from `InputDataBaseClass` **it does not mean that** `ITestInterface<InputDataConcreteClass1>` inherits from `ITestInterface<InputDataBaseClass>`. It doesn't.

Comment: And it's not a limitation of interfaces in C#. It's how they're meant to work.

Comment: It you are creating an interface for the base class then you can only have properties that are in the base class and not properties in the two inherited classes.  The interface will then work for the two inherited classes.

Comment: C# does not allow such use of interfaces for good reason (consider what happens with `List<T> : IAddToList<T>`). In your case you have to pair the correct `TestInterfaceImpl` with the `InputDataConcreteClass`. Have you thought how that happens? What is `TestInterfaceImpl2` going to do when its `SomeMethod` gets called with a `InputDataDerived1` through the interface?

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti

Could you point me to an example? I don't quite understand how that would work.

Comment: @Enigmativity

Fair enought, is there an alternative approach to what I want to do then?

Comment: @jdweng

Please see my Edit1 - is that what you are suggesting? I realize this can work (and it does) but... casting input data like that inside the implementation makes interfaces pretty error prone and requires run time check of the passed input data type.

Comment: @AntonTykhyy

OK, so is there any alternative then? Other then manual casting I posted in Edit1?

Comment: Please think about the two questions in my previous comment. There must be a line in your code somewhere that knows enough to give `TestInterfaceImpl1` a `InputDataDerivedClass1` and `TestInterfaceImpl2` a `InputDataDerivedClass2`. Where is it? What do you need `ITestInterface` for in the first place?

Comment: @AntonTykhyy:

Please see my Edit2. The problem I'm facing is that my interface has to implement a method that processes the same logic but use slightly different input data in each implementation. For example, I have method SaveData - one implementation saves it to the database and requires data plus a set of foreign keys, while the other saves it to the disk and requires data plus the file name. Until now, I always did like I shown in the Edit2 - and it worked great... But sometimes it can be cumbersome to inject everything in the constructor of the implementation.

Comment: @AntonTykhyy:

And as for your previous question: "TestInterfaceImpl2 going to do when its SomeMethod gets called with a InputDataDerived1" - I don't really see how that suppose to happen? While the interface allows any class based on the InputDataBaseClass to implement it, the implementation I proposed for the TestInterfaceImpl2 - will not allow you to call SomeMethod with anything different than the InputDataDerivedClass2 (that was the base idea, so each implementation could have its own input data type for the method). Perhaps what I'm trying to do is simply impossible

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't sound like a workable idea to me. You're splitting your abstractions in the wrong place. If you need to pass a lot of data to the implementation's constructor, you wrap those data into an object and supply it to the constructor at the spot where you're building your resolution root. If you don't want to create the (e.g.) `ToDatabaseSaver` instance when building the resolution root, you can e.g. with NInject do it like this `kernel.Bind<IDataSaver> ().To<ToDatabaseSaver> ().WithConstructorArgument (...)`.

Comment: @AntonTykhyy:

I realize I can use dependency injection and it works perfectly that way... I was just curious if there is another way, that would allow me to move most parameters from the constructor to the method, and yet stay flexible. I guess, there isn't any good way to do that (unless we use casting, but this is counterproductive to what I want to achieve). I suppose I will stick with the constructor injection, then.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: you can work this around by using e.g JObject as parameter type... convert your parameter to JObject and then again convert back to expected type... I am looking for solution for exact same problem and currently following JObject appraoch